# Jquery .load 404 - How do I absolute path this?

Tags: jquery

First off thanks for any help in advance as always.

I'm trying to use Jquery .load to bring in a php file into a specified #div once it has been emptied. The php file has no errors and performs as expected however no matter how I specify the file location I get a 404 with firebug and I can't find seem to specify a absolute path like I can with php. This is such a simple thing and driving me CRAZY!

Here's the code (I've included the php ABSPATH as an example:

```
    <?php include (ABSPATH.'/wp-content/themes/bigformat/template-home-search.php');?>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $("#performsearch").click(function(){
        $("#displayresults").empty();
        $( "#displayresults" ).load( "/template-home-search.php", function( response, status, xhr ) {
  if ( status == "error" ) {
    var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
    $( "#error" ).html( msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText );
  }
});
        return false;
    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: /template-home-search.php means that the file is on your root dir, is it?!\

Comment: No. To clarify I'm using Wordpress and the file is located at /wp-content/themes/bigformat/template-home-search.php - But if I change the url it still 404's. Really weird.

Comment: Interestingly if I put a version of the file at the root dir I get a '500' error.

Comment: I've solved it. Looks like the Javascript did not like to load the WPQUERY used in wordpress through the php. - Advice to anyone else having issues. Use firebug then check your server log error files.